# How to add delay between two requests using Volley on Android

Tags: android, http, httprequest, android-volley

I have a situation where I need to wait 5-10 seconds between two HTTP requests. I'm trying to use Volley in order to create the HTTP requests. I read into the RequestFuture class, but I couldn't find good documentation on it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: did you want the two requests have communication to decide which one should be wait? or just wish the individual one being waiting.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Can't you just use Handler class to delay the execution of adding the request to the queue?